# In Swift, when would I use a "while let"?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm watching a tutorial where the author used **while let** while he was looping. Why? I didn't find anything on `while let`, so can somebody explain it to me?

```
while let node = currentNode {
    print(node.value, terminator: "->")
    currentNode = node.next
}
```

Comment: It's a little dry, but `while let` grammar is outlined in the reference section of [The Swift Programming Language: Language Reference: Statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID432).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code traverses over a node and its successor

```
while let node = currentNode { // check a root node
   print(node.value, terminator: "->") // print current node value 
   currentNode = node.next // go deep to its next one 
}
```

until it gets the leave node where the `while let` will stop  as `node.next` is nil , its same as

```
while currentNode != nil { // check a root node
   print(currentNode?.value, terminator: "->") // print current node value 
   currentNode = currentNode?.next // go deep to its next one 
}
```

> `While let` someVar

> > means execute what inside the block until someVar is nil

Comment: That's not entirely correct, `node` will be unwrapped in the body of the `let`, so the equivalent `print` code would be `print(currentNode!.value, terminator: "->")`

Comment: `currentNode` is optional so i could use both `currentNode?` and `currentNode!` even if it's not nil

Comment: Ofcourse, but it's not the same :). `currentNode?. value` returns an optional, while the code from the question prints a non-optional. This is why I said the code from the answer is not entirely equivalent to the one from the question.

Comment: @Cristik this isn't a big deal it's a print statement actually it doesn't deserve a conversation

Comment: Then don't call it "its same as", it's misleading

Answer (score 4):

To cut it short, `while let`, `if let` or anything merged with let is used to make sure that this value isn't nil and it has a value already so here in your case, the developer is double checking if `current node != nil` to be able to continue in the case inside the block of the while statement